# Netezza External Table (no. of columns restriction)

Tags: external, netezza

I have a flat file of 367 columns. Can it be loaded using external concept?
Is there any restriction in the number of columns which is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The limits for external tables are the same as the limits for regular database tables. The current limits for a table are 1600 columns, with a maximum rowsize of 64K.  Your flat file with 367 columns should not be a problem as long as the maximum row size is within that limit.